# Array not getting populated by my function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am trying to simplify adding stuff to some arrays with a custom function in PHP.

```
 $campaignLimits    = array();
 $couponLimits      = array();
 $subscriptions     = array();
```

The function looks like this:

```
 function DefineSubscription($itemname,$subscription,$campaignlimit,$couponlimit)
 {
    // Make em global
    global $campaignLimits, $couponLimits, $subscriptions;

    // Add stuff to the arrays
    $campaignLimits[$itemname]      = $campaignlimit;
    $couponLimits[$itemname]        = $couponlimit; 
    $subscriptions[$itemname]       = $subscription;
    return;
 }
```

I am calling that function, like this:

```
 DefineSubscription(
                    "1",    // Item Name/Number
                    1,      // Subscription ID
                    1,      // Campaign Limit
                    30      // Coupon Limit
                    );
```

However, when I `print_r($couponLimits);`, I get `Array`.

The function and the Arrays are declared in a `require_once`'d file.

I am obviously doing something wrong.. But what? :)

**EDIT:** By doing the print_r in the DefineSubscription function itself, I got the correct output. It appears my arrays are not global when I am including it? Isn't it supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using global vars you should adresse them with $GLOBALS to make sure your in the right context

```
$GLOBALS['campaignLimits']    = array();
$GLOBALS['couponLimits']      = array();
$GLOBALS['subscriptions']     = array();

function DefineSubscription () { ... }

DefineSubscription(...);

print_r($GLOBALS['campaignLimits']);
```

Regards Thomas

Comment: I have done this kind of coding before, and I never had to declare them with $GLOBALS - will try anyway tho.

Comment: It is not necesary to declare the variables in the $GLOBALS array, just in the access: print_r($GLOBALS['couponLimits'], true)

Comment: Never had to do that either, weird :O

Comment: you don't have to use $GLOBALS to declare a global variable if your in the global-context...

Answer (score 0):

Array ( [1] => 30 )

I got that by print_r'ing `$couponLimits` ...

well i put the all in a page though...

try debugging by adding values on declarations, and `print_r` right after you `require_once` or try `include` instead...

Comment: I kinda need `require_once`, cause.. the file is required. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ambit. 
1) You declare $couponLimits in the main program
2) LATER, when the function is called, you declare global $couponLimits
3) You call $couponLimits in the main page, it is refered to the local one, not the global.

If you want your "main" $couponLimits to be global, you must declare it as global.

```
global $campaignLimits;
global $couponLimits;
global $subscriptions;
```

insted of

```
$campaignLimits    = array();
$couponLimits      = array();
$subscriptions     = array();
```